# FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

hello I have created new instance on aws ec2 and deployed node project whenever I hit any api its taking too much time and after on console I got this error

[image]

[image]

I have tried many solutions but not worked on my old aws instance it is working properly

Comment: Can you share more information about your EC2 characteristics?  Looks like your application has a memory leak.

Comment: what type of information you want ?

Comment: **Do the following:** After you run your app in the EC2, execute the top command to check how much memory is free for further processes.

Comment: @ Eleazar Enrique which command ?

Comment: `top`  <- that command will show you information about your operating system like memory, CPU, etc.

Comment: 422056k is free and it keep changing